# Where should I put continue for the code to go back to top of the loop?

Tags: python

So, I'm making a code where it asks for my name and then asks me if I'm sure that's my name. If I answer 'S' it continues, if I answer 'N' it asks me for my name again and it should go back to top of the loop and ask me if I'm sure, but it doesn't. If I don't answer neither 'S' nor 'N', it asks me again if I'm sure.

```py
print('Hi! Whats your name?')
nome = input().title()
while len(nome) < 3 or len(nome) > 10:
    print('That name doesnt sound real. Please, tell me your real name.')
    nome = input().title()
else:
    respostass = ['Sim', 'S']
    respostasn = ['Não', 'N', 'Nao']
    print('Are you sure your names ' + nome + '?')
    certeza = input().title()
    while certeza not in respostass and certeza not in respostasn:
        print('I did not understood what you meant. Are you sure or not?')
        certeza = input().title()
    if certeza in respostass:
        print("Nice. Let us continue.")
    else:
        print('So, whats your name?')
        nome = input().title()
        continue
```

It gives me this error:

```py
  File "C:/Users/Hugo/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 22
    continue
    ^
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

Comment: The `else` block is not in the loop. It will only be used after your `while` loop is done. So at that point there is nothing to go back to. i.e. `continue` is not needed

Comment: Your need to escape the quote, like in `What's`, `doesn't`, `name's`, ...etc

Comment: Thanks, @Buckeye14Guy. So, how can I make it so that else becomes part of the loop? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Oh, that's my bad, @trincot. The original code is in portuguese and I forgot that when translating it. I'll change it.

Comment: `else` is complimentary to `while`. It is totally ok to use a `while...else` or `for...else` expression

Comment: @Almeidowski my updated answer should help a bit. I think you should weight more on the ['Sim' or 'S'] answers so I changed the last while loop to reflect that. Handle one response at a time so if the user says No then go back and ask for the name but if the answer is nonsensical then simply ask them to confirm [yes or no]

Comment: Simply wrap the whole `while` loop with another `while True:`.

Answer (score 0):

While formatting this I noticed you had some string issues. Please use `" "` and `' '` accordingly or you could have more syntax errors. But you don't really need a `continue` statement. I think you want to stop after the user confirms right?

```py
print("Hi! What's your name?")
nome = input().title()
while len(nome) < 3 or len(nome) > 10:
    print("That name doesn't sound real. Please, tell me your real name.")
    nome = input().title()
else:
    respostass = ['Sim', 'S']
    respostasn = ['Não', 'N', 'Nao']
    print("Are you sure your name's " + nome + '?')
    certeza = input().title()
    while certeza not in respostass:
        if certeza not in respostasn:
            print('I did not understood what you meant. Are you sure or not?')
            certeza = input().title()
        else:
            print("So, what's your name?")
            nome = input().title()
            print("Are you sure your name's " + nome + '?')
            certeza = input().title()
```

Comment: Did you test your answer? Is it working as desired?

Comment: Your advice about the string may help a bit but do you really know if your answer solves the problem?

Comment: But if I answer a 'No' to that last question or something that's not on the list, the code will continue instead of going back. That's the problem. @EDIT oh ok I got it now. Thanks a lot Buckeye14Guy